# Arduino monitor printing out wrong variable value

Tags: c, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Hello my problem is whenever I type in a value for my variable "var" and then print it. It will give me a completely different value. For example if I type "5" it will print me the decimal value ( which is 53 ) this can be frustrating as you see i'm trying to match one number to another and this is causing an issue.

NOTE: I have tried changing the if (Serial.available() > 0) to a while condition with no luck. And I am also using a 16x2 lcd display.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int backLight = 13;
int var=0;
int password=5320;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(backLight, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(backLight, HIGH);
  lcd.begin(16,2);              
  lcd.clear();                  
  Serial.println("Enter password");
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    var = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(var);
    if (var==password)
    {
      lcd.clear();                  
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Access granted");
    }    
    else
    {
      lcd.clear();                  
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Access denied");
    }
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string input into an int.  Using a function.  And you need to read in the characters into an array, no just an int.  For example, perhaps:

```
char var[10];
int i = 0; // index
while (Serial.Available() > 0){
    char readval = Serial.Read();
    var[i++] = readval;
}
var[i] = 0;  // null terminate string
int int_of_var = atoi(var);
```

Note that although 5320 can fit into a single integer, the characters '5', '3', '2', '0' require 4 bytes to hold them (plus a byte for null termination).

Comment: "   In function 'void loop()':                                                          error: incompatible types of 'int' to 'char[10]'  " Is the error message I am recieving. I had never encountered this problem when I had the lcd screen disconnected, this is fairly simple I am only working with integers and comparing them.